# Toolbar's bottom border isn't displayed normally under menu item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have implemented border at the bottom of toolbar. If I don't display any menu item, it looks great. The following image shows us the current look of my toolbar. I don't know any idea why border is thick under menu item. How can I solve this problem?

[image: thickToolBarBottomBorder]

styles.xml

```
<style name="MyCustomToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/Blue</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bottom_border_blue</item>

</style>
```

app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_50"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:theme="@style/MyCustomToolBarTheme">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_17"
        android:textColor="@color/Blue"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

bottom_border_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/Blue" />
            <solid android:color="@color/White" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/White" />
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

menu_boat.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/editButton"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/edit"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

BoatActivity.java

```
public class BoatActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView titleTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_boat);

        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");

        titleTextView=(TextView)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbarTitleTextView);
        titleTextView.setText(R.string.myBoat);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back_button);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_boat, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Set height of your TextView as match_parent.

Comment: I tried but there is no change. @ZsoltBoldizsár

Comment: Where is the action item. Please edit your xml.

Comment: Set height of your toolbar to ?android:attr/actionBarSize and also remove minHeight property.

Comment: There is no line under menu item when I use "?android:attr/actionBarSize " and remove minHeight attribute. It looks like as a dashed line. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the bottom_border_blue background as the background of your toolbar in the xml and check if it works.

Comment: Great answer. It works perfectly. Thank you but I can't understand what is the difference between defining in the "app:theme" and toolbar's background. Why is it not same ? @umesh lohani